# c# The ManagementEventWatcher event EventArrivedEventHandler is sending me random infor

Tags: c#, wpf, usb

I am using C#.
When I plug in my USB device the event fires but it keep firing like 10 times in a row and when I remove it, the remove event fires does the same thing.
and it does not event remove it from my list

how do I only return the new connected USB device and remove the new disconnected USB?
here is my code:

```cs
public USBControl()
{
    // Add USB plugged event watching
    watcherAttach = new ManagementEventWatcher();
    watcherAttach.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventArrived);
    watcherAttach.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
    watcherAttach.Start();

    // Add USB unplugged event watching
    watcherRemove = new ManagementEventWatcher();

    watcherRemove.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(watcher_EventRemoved);
    watcherRemove.Query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3");
    watcherRemove.Start();
}
    
void watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Watcher EventArrived 
    var collection  = (ManagementEventWatcher) sender;
    USBDeviceList.Add(sender);
}

void watcher_EventRemoved(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < USBDeviceList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (USBDeviceList[i] == sender)
        {
            USBDeviceList.RemoveAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really sending you random info? Did you actually look at the info it's sending you, i.e. the `NewEvent` property of the `e` parameter? I don't see any evidence of it in that code. Without ever having done this myself, I'd guess that there is different information in there each time and you need to filter on that data to determine the specific event(s) you need to act upon.

Comment: The information is consistent, but I only want to USB I just enter information not all the other stuff